# Deploy Simple Go Webapp to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Go app to Elastic beanstalk (through the UI)

What I've done:

- Created a single application.go file which listens on Port 5000
- Compiled for Linux (set GOOS=linux and GOARCH=amd64) using the command found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go-environment.html

  - go build -o bin/application application.go
- zipped the bin folder and uploaded it to Elastic Beanstalk (I've also tried uploading the file without the bin folder)

For development I'm using go version go1.18.1 windows/amd64

Under Platform in Elastic Beanstalk I see: Go 1 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.5.1

According to  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.go
go v. 1.18.1 is supported

My Code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    fmt.Println("Now serving!!!")
    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)
}
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "My Res !!! %s", time.Now())
}
```

The Application health is "no data".

With the most recent event of "Environment health has transitioned from Pending to No Data. None of the instances are sending data."

When I look in chrome dev tools and try to open the link, I just get (failed) net:ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. "Failed to load response data: No Resource with given identifier found"

**Potential Issues:**

- When I look at the configuration tab, I see that this environment is not part of a VPC. Could that be the issue?

**Some Potential Next Steps:**

- Test running on WSL
- Test deploying on a standalone EC2
- Try deploying through the CLI
- Try wrapping in a docker container and deploying docker (though this wouldn't actually solve my problem, I'd like to be able to deploy without docker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue using your code, but **everything is fine**. My EB environment works and deploys perfectly with your code.

The only thing I can think of is that I used linux to create my binary, while you've used `windows/amd64`. I don't think those binaries are interchangeable.

Comment: I am compiling for linux, but I haven't actually tested that it runs on linux, that'll be my next step

Comment: So now it's working fine. I looked in the sample app and it was not compiled. I'm uploading a zip folder with the source files (Which is what I originally did in the first place :/ ) so I'm not sure what is different.